# Why does QGIS v.clean toolset create result many times more than the original layers?

Tags: qgis

I am trying to correct overlap topology error type of a polygon layer. The red line marks the places where there were overlapping errors on this particular layer.
[image]

I tried to use the v,clean toolset from the QGIS toolbox to correct the errors from the layer. The tool corrects the errors from the layer but on opening the attribute table i noticed that the result was almost 3 times the number of the original number of polygons. Pls can anyone advice on how to use the tool or any other approach in correcting overlap topology error of polygon layers in QGIS.

Comment: It is a GRASS GIS command :  [v.clean](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/v.clean.html) and  [GRASS GIS wiki; Vector topology cleaning](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Vector_topology_cleaning)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Try to use remove dupplicate (rmdupl). Use it several times with v.clean.advanced tool. Hope it helps.